# Vim syntastic is not showing warning messages

Tags: vim, jslint, syntastic

This is my current syntastic configuration:

```
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "level": [] }
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint', 'jslint']
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = 'WW'
let g:syntastic_error_symbol = 'EE'
```

The problem that I have is that, it shows only error messages in my javascript files:

For example:

```
% jslint web/js/app.js

web/js/app.js
 #1 'define' was used before it was defined.
    define([ // Line 1, Pos 1
 #2 Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.
    RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation) { // Line 73, Pos 58
```

but when I open the file in vim i see only the message `#1 'define' was used before it was defined.`, not the second one.

What should I do to enable warnings to be shown too?

Comment: There's no way to tell which of the two items is an error and which is a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntastic uses the following command line options to `jslint` by default:

```
--white --nomen --regexp --plusplus --bitwise --newcap --sloppy --vars
```

(see `syntastic/syntax_checkers/javascript/jslint.vim`).
You can set your own options via

```
let g:syntastic_javscript_jslint_args = "--foo --bar --baz"
```

The `--white` from the defaults is what suppresses your second warning